# Openconnect in Juniper mode suddenly fails with "Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie"

Tags: 16.04, networking, vpn, openconnect

I've been using Openconnect on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to connect to my VPN successfully for quite a while, using the following options to invoke the Juniper support and set up a SOCKS5 tunnel

*(Note the real VPN URL has been replaced with vpn.company.com)*

```
openconnect --juniper 
            --script-tun --script "/usr/bin/ocproxy -D 11080"  
            --cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/vpn1.company.com.der
            https://vpn.company.com
```

After rebooting over lunch, I was no longer able to reconnect, but instead got the following transcript ending in error:

```
WARNING: Juniper Network Connect support is experimental.
It will probably be superseded by Junos Pulse support.
GET https://vpn.company.com/
Attempting to connect to server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
SSL negotiation with vpn.company.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.company.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
GET https://vpn.company.com/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi
SSL negotiation with vpn.company.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.company.com
frmLogin
GET https://vpn.company.com/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi
SSL negotiation with vpn.company.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.company.com
frmLogin
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

The network support team isn't aware of any issues with their Juniper VPN, but I am suddenly not even getting to the password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be a manual upgrade of Openconnect.

Via `apt-get install --upgrade-only openconnect`, I confirmed I was already on the latest version (7.06-2build2)

I [downloaded the latest version](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/download.html) (7.08) and [built it manually](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/building.html).  Since the `vpnc-scripts` package puts the vpnc-script in a different location than the default, I needed to give that info `configure`.  I also didn't care about missing DTLS support, so told it to just use my current version of openssl:

```
./configure --with-vpnc-script=/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script --without-openssl-version-check
```

as well as add a few missing packages needed for the build - in my case `libxml2`, `libxml2-dev`, and `pkg-config`.

Finally, since the Xenial packaged used GnuTLS, but my build was using OpenSSL, it couldn't read the cert file as a .der and got a `Failed to open CA file`.  This was fixed by converting it to a .pem (the OpenSSL default):

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/vpn1.company.com.der -inform der 
             -out /etc/ssl/certs/vpn1.company.com.pem -outform pem
```

I suspect there had been a change on the VPN server side that began sending a "Pre Sign-in Message" which is now [supported in 7.08](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/changelog.html).